# GAS and Google Docs: makeCopy() and manipulate body

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to build an add-on for Google Spreadsheet that takes a Google Doc as a template and replaces marked passages with values from the Spreadsheet. To achieve that goal, I put together a sidebar add-on so that the user can select the lines he wants to be processed and then can click a button to run the script.

The sidebar itself is working and successfully calling the custom function. The custom function itself is also working but due to limited authorization (see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/lifecycle) it is only allowed to read the template file and make a copy of it. When I then try to access the newly created file through `openById()` it denies the request.

I guess since the restriction on access is actually by design, I need to modify the process, for example doing the manipulation when I am creating the copy. Unfortunately I cannot really figure out how to do that. I tried `getContent()` but that returns the content as a PDF document. `getBody()` doesn't work on a copy.

I am very thankful for any help.

The custom function looks like this:

```
function createLetter(data, header) {

  var template = '1HsJsXgQr_GSUr0elF4llM-0QKj5ocjPmaNVSE3Eka2Q'
  var name = data[5]

  var doc = DriveApp.getFileById(template).makeCopy('TEST-Aufnahmeschreiben ' + name).

  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "CET", "dd.MM.YYYY")

  var doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy).getBody()

  for (i in header) {
    doc.replaceText('{'+header[i]+'}', data[i])
  }

  if (data[4] == 1) {doc.replaceText('{Salutation}', 'Lieber')} else {doc.replaceText('{Salutation}', 'Liebe')};

  doc.replaceText('{Datum}', date);
  doc.replaceText('{Land}', 'Deutschland');

  return copy;
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this, I have the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, sorry. Have you tried getBlob()? If you can grab the content, it seems like that would work. You can then turn a blob into a string, which you would be able to work with.